# Getting a return variable from user input to pass to a different module

Tags: python

I have my main module. In side the main module the function age is defined to get a user to input there age for determining content. here is the def of the function.

```
def age():
    print("")
    time.sleep(0.0)
    playerage=int(input(""))
    time.sleep(0.0)
    print("Thank you.")
    if playerage>=18:
        ac1()
    elif playerage<=18:
        kc1()
    return playerage
```

That function works properly when i call the variable playerage later in the main module. I need to pass the variable for playerage to a separate module in a different file. Both files are in the same root folder. Here is the code i have tried to get the variable passed into the other module.

```
import main_module
age=main_module.age
if age>=18:
    print("adult")
else:
    print("child")
```

Thanks in advance for any help for a new and learning programmer!

```
I made a few issues when editing the names of my files and such after copy and pasting to here. I tried the suggestions, and i apologize, but i didn't properly have my code represented so i want to post what it is now as i wasn't able to make it work with the suggestions since my code was a little bit different. 

First, i have created a blank file names __init__.py

Here is the code from the "main_module" defining the age function. 

    def age():
    print("some words")
    time.sleep(0.0)
    playerage=int(input("some words"))
    time.sleep(0.0)
    print("Thank you.")
    if playerage>=18:
        adultchoice1()
    elif playerage<=18:
        kidchoice1()
    return playerage

That is the main file for my program. the age function is defined there with the code above. then the third_file needs the variable from age. Here is the entire test code i wrote for trying to figure this out.

    #name

import time
import main_module

def dragon_opening():
    print("")
    age=int(main_module.age())
    print(age)
    if age>=18:
        print("adult")
    else:
        print("child")
if __name__ == '__main__':        
    dragon_opening()
    time.sleep(15.0)

Here is the code that calls third_file to run.

    if playervariable==1:
        print("some words")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        import third_file.dragon_opening

Here is the error that is generated when i run the code.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'third_file.dragon_opening'; 'thrid_file' is not a package

Again my apologies to those who answered my erroneously copied code from my first post. Also a big thanks to those of you who replied to my initial post and any who post after this!
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty file named

```
__init__.py
```

in your directory, then use:

```
from main_module import age
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Demodred!

Right now you assigned your variable `age` to the function itself, but you need to include brackets to actually run it and get its result:

```
age=main_module.age()
```

Try using `print` right now on `age` and you'll see that it's not what you're expecting.